# ssh always times out

Tags: ssh

I'm quite new to ssh, trying to use it to get a remote command line on my home PC from school.

As an Arch user, I followed the Arch Wiki's instructions on setting up ssh by enabling sshd.service. I changed the port to 8160 as it was recommended that I change it from 22 to use it across a WAN (i.e. the Internet), and I verified that this was not a port that was in known popular use on Wikipedia.

Yet, when I go to another PC in my house and search for 'what's my IP' on Google, use that and the port 8160 in Putty on Windows to connect, it says it times out. Why is this?

Comment: You surely have a router between your PC at home and the internet. So you would have to do a port forwarding at your router from <external-ip>:8160 to <your-pc>:22. If you are behind a router you do not need to change the SSH listening port from 22, but just add a forward in your router's firewall.

Comment: To test your local configuration, you can instead use the address you get from `ip addr` on the machine running sshd (it's probably `192.168.x.y`). This will only work from your own network (inside your house, basically), but it will make sure you've got sshd set up correctly.

Comment: Are you able to connect to localhost on the machine where you are running sshd? For example: `ssh -p 8160 localhost`

Comment: @Thomas thank you; this was it. I made my own answer but realized I can only accept it in two days; mind making your own and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely have a router between your PC at home and the internet.

So you would have to do a port forwarding at your router from `<external-ip>:8160` to `<your-pc>:22`.
If you are behind a router you do not need to change the SSH listening port from 22, but just add a forward in your router's firewall.